# xcode7にて「Xcode cannot run using the selected device」と出て実機テストが出来ません

Tags: xcode

Xcode7にて無料で実機テストが出来ると聞き、Xcode7で実機テストをしてみました。
すると、表題の通り、

Xcode cannot run using the selected device.

と出てしまい実機テストができない状態です。
またエミュレーターを選ぶ部分の
ineligible deviseにはunavailableと出てしまい、それを選択して実機テストをしようとしても

Could not find Developer Disk Image

となってしまいます。
解決策を教えてください。

・使用OSや実機のスペック
Xcode7 beta
Mac Os：10.10.4
IOS実機：iphone4s IOS8.4

・Xcodeの設定
IOS deployment Target:8.4

Comment: まったくおなじ障害が、こちらでも発生しています。Appleの認証システムの不具合で、一時的なものと信じたいのですが……

Comment: http://seiya-orz.hatenablog.com
いま調べていたのですが、どうやらxcode7betaではIOS8.4対応のimage diskが入っていないようです。
xcode6.4には入っているようなので、そこからコピペをして稼働してみます。

Comment: ご紹介のリンク先の方法で、ぶじ実機にインストールが成功しました。ありがとうございました。できれば、自己回答の形をとっていただけたらと思います。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

参考ブログ：[seiya-orz.hatenablog.com](http://seiya-orz.hatenablog.com/)

いま調べていたのですが、どうやらxcode7betaではIOS8.4対応のimage diskが入っていないようです。 xcode6.4には入っているようなので、そこからコピペをして稼働してみます。

Answer (score 0):

記事のURLが変更になりましたので、こちらを参考にしてください。
http://seiya-orz.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/07/05/163207